# pandas: unexpected join behavior results in NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that I'm trying to join in pandas (version 0.18.1).

```
test1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': range(1,6), 'place': ['Kent','Lenawee','Washtenaw','Berrien','Ottawa']})

  id_1      place
0   1       Kent
1   2    Lenawee
2   3   Montreal
3   4    Berrien
4   5     Ottawa


test2 = pd.DataFrame({'id_2': range(6,11), 'id_parent': range(1,6)})

   id_2  id_parent
0     6          1
1     7          2
2     8          3
3     9          4
4    10          5
```

Yet when I join the two tables, the last row doesn't join properly and, because it's a left join, results in NaN.

```
df = test2.join(test1,on='id_parent',how='left')

   id_2  id_parent  id_1      place
0     6          1     2    Lenawee
1     7          2     3   Montreal
2     8          3     4    Berrien
3     9          4     5     Ottawa
4    10          5   NaN        NaN
```

This doesn't make sense to me-- id_parent and id_1 are the keys on which to join the two tables, and they both have the same value. Both columns have the same dtype (int64). What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#joining-key-columns-on-an-index) joins primarily on indices, use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) for this:

```
In [18]:
test2.merge(test1,left_on='id_parent', right_on='id')

Out[18]:
   id_2  id_parent  id      place
0     6          1   1       Kent
1     7          2   2    Lenawee
2     8          3   3  Washtenaw
3     9          4   4    Berrien
4    10          5   5     Ottawa
```

You get the `NaN` because the rhs will use the rhs index and there is no entry for `0` and `5` so you get `NaN`

Comment: Ah...I assumed I should use .join() since in SQL I think this would have been a join. Oops. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here I quote the documentation of pandas : 'join takes an optional on argument which may be a column or multiple column names, which specifies that the passed DataFrame is to be aligned on that column in the DataFrame. "

So in your case, you are matching the index of test2 on id_parent from test1.